# Get list of names in rich text editor started with @ symbol

Tags: syncfusion

We are using Syncfusion Rich Text Editor(RTE) in our .Net application along with Azure Search. This RTE is used like a comment box for each and every particular blog post.

So, Whenever any user want to post their comment in the RTE they can tag specific user along with their names .

To do this we want to make an azure search call to get the list of all possible users names as soon as they typed @ along with some key word . Just like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When typing @ symbol, we can get the list of names in the RTE component using the Atjs integration in the component. For more information on this, refer to the following link to the documentation:
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/rich-text-editor/third-party-integration/#atjs-integration